# Error processing package sane-utils (--configure)

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, package-management, scanner

I'm trying to run the command "*sudo apt upgrade*" and I see this error which is not allowing me to install ubuntu-desktop on my CLI based server.  Is there any way that I can fix this issue or please let me know how to install ubuntu-desktop GUI on Ubuntu server(CLI)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up sane-utils (1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.1) ...
gpasswd: group 'scanner' does not exist in /etc/group
adduser: `/usr/bin/gpasswd -a saned scanner' returned error code 3. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package sane-utils (--configure):
 installed sane-utils package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sane-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `grep -r scanner /etc/group*` please. Edit your question for output.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post images of code/errors, rather copy and paste them into the body of the question.

Comment: I am still getting this error no matter how many times I try this. My ubuntu server environment is not letting me reboot I guess.